# OracleDataSource and validationQuery

Tags: oracle

I was wondering does the class oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource offer the user the option of specifying a validation query?
I was looking in the api but couldnt find anything

I noticed org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource offers a validationQuery but for 2 of my datasources, I need to use the OracleDataSource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solition was to set a connectionCacheProperty on our connection

```
<property name="connectionCacheProperties">
        <map>   
            <entry key="ValidateConnection" value="true" />
        </map>
    </property>
```